# Not sure if I should close my question or not

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38881187/403404), which isn't a duplicate, but during troubleshooting it turns out the root cause was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777200/403404) somewhere else.  So, which of the following should I do?

- Close my question
- Offer for the answer author to post his answer on my question
- Answer it myself when the 2 days pass
- Some other fourth option?

Comment: 1 2 and 3 all seem fine. 2 though is a bit weird...

Comment: Ha, for some reason I thought I had to wait, was thinking about bounty I guess.

Comment: Must have been, been a long time since I answered my own question, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone remembers VirtualBox guest additions, skip this paragraph. VirtualBox guest additions "fix" all sorts of issues/problems, from hardware acceleration, to usb3 support (I think is still like that), to sharing directories between host and guest.

Closing the question as duplicated isn't appropriated, because even after you reduced the problem but couldn't identify any common cause with the would-be-target, then obviously they are not the "same problem", but share the same solution. The same would be for two problems that can be solved by restarting Windows.

Now, closing your question for any other reason doesn't seems to be very productive either. You are able to reproduce the issue and it isn't immediately obvious a mistake of your part (like a dirty environment), so I can't think of any reason that you would close it.

For answer it yourself, you can add not only the "solution" but also the "why" this solution solves the problem, and how to identify the problem, if your question hasn't done so.

Answer (score 0):

The following close reason is pretty much an exact match for your situation:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Actually, I disagree.  My specific problem is reproducible, and my question was a symptom that people (in similar circumstances) would be searching for.

Comment: @JohnieKarr It's not reproducible given the information in the question.  You had an unrelated configuration problem with your environment.  This is the appropriate close reason for such a situation; it's literally why it exists.

Comment: though technically you are correct, the misconfiguration was the problem, not the symptom.  Even in the question where the appropriate answer was, it wasn't evidently clear from the OP that this misconfiguration was the cause.  Therefore, someone with the same problem would be looking for this symptom, and find the answer helpful.  I tend to search for the symptom I'm having because I can't figure out the problem.  Maybe it's a bad assumption that others search this way as well :)

Comment: @JohnieKarr Why ask if you should close the quesiton if you are going to out of hand reject the possibility that the question merits closure, even when presented with a close reason that is specifically designed for this exact type of question?  If you don't care that your question is unanswerable, and that your quesiton merits closure, then why ask the quesiton?  If you think that questions shouldn't be closed for being unanswerable and having problems that aren't reproducible and are unrelated to the question asked, then you could propose a change for that, I guess.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think we might be misunderstanding each other.  I'm not rejecting the possibility that the question merits closure.  I'm saying the reason you give as merit for closure isn't applicable.  I apologize if I, in any way, offended you.

Comment: @JohnieKarr The close reason *exists* for environmental and configuration issues unrelated to the question asked, which is exactly what this is.  You're saying that you don't think that the close reason should exist, which is different.

Comment: Actually, the close reason you posted has no mention of the words environmental or configuration.  The problem was NOT a simple typographical error, and this problem was resolved in such a way that WOULD help future readers.  I'm not saying this close reason shouldn't exist.  I'm saying it doesn't apply to my question.